# How to make a status update from iPhone App using SDK 3.5?

Tags: iphone, ios, facebook

I have integrated facebook SDK 3.5 with my iPhone app. Authorisation, login working perfectly fine but I am unable to figure out how to do a status update. Some code will be helpful.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

There you go: pass your FBID below and test it.. You can pass on your friend's FBID as well in order to post on their wall.. For more info read - developers.facebook.com/docs for iOS.

```
 NSMutableDictionary *params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                   YourFBID,@"to",
                                   nil];

    [FBWebDialogs presentFeedDialogModallyWithSession:[FBSession activeSession]
                                           parameters:params
                                              handler:
     ^(FBWebDialogResult result, NSURL *resultURL, NSError *error) {
         if (error) {
             // Error launching the dialog or publishing a story.
             NSLog(@"Error publishing story.");
         } else {
             // Success here

             }             
         }
     }];
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Hey, thanks a ton for the code. It is working. But I want to do something slightly different. It is asking me what to post. I want to post static text every time. So is it possible to somehow autofill the dialog with the text ?
It will work even if it doesn't show the dialog and just simply post to facebook .
Thanks again

Answer (score 1):

You can post the status only after you gets the access token. Once you get the access token then use the following code to post status

```
    NSString *name = self.loggedInUser.first_name;
NSString *message = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Hello Friends i am %@ i created this app on Date %@ using facebook SDK.",name,[NSDate date]];

// if it is available to us, we will post using the native dialog
BOOL displayedNativeDialog = [FBNativeDialogs presentShareDialogModallyFrom:self
                                                                initialText:nil
                                                                      image:nil
                                                                        url:nil
                                                                    handler:nil];
if (!displayedNativeDialog) {

    [self performPublishAction:^{
        // otherwise fall back on a request for permissions and a direct post
    [FBRequestConnection startForPostStatusUpdate:message
    completionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) 
                {
                   [self showAlert:message result:result error:error];
                   self.buttonPostStatus.enabled = YES;
                }];

    }];
```

Comment: There is a sample project named **HelloFaceBookSameple** which can help you for sure.

Comment: Which delegate I have to add in order to call 'performPublishAction' method ? Right now it says no such selector.

Comment: You need add facebooksdk in header file **#import <FacebookSDK/FacebookSDK.h>**  and then **<FBLoginViewDelegate>**. Hope that will help.

Comment: I have done the same but still it is not recognizing 'performPublishAction' method

Comment: I think the reason is you have not added the SDK properly. or may be you have not added the **FacebookSDKResources.bundle** Or **FBUserSettingsViewResources.bundle**

Comment: Everything is there, I don't know what is wrong. You are telling this for Facebook SDK 3.5, right ?

Comment: I am talking the latest version of Facebook SDK... I think you should google with the error you are getting you can find a solution easily for these type of problems.